# Android Material toolbar goes up when keyboard appears

Tags: android, material-design

I've tried every solution and it still doesn't work for me. From adjustPan to adjustNothing.

What I want is that my whole header should remain as it is when the keyboard appears. No hiding and all that of header. Right now, here's the sequence:

**1. How I want it to look always**
[image]

**2. Here comes evil keyboard. (See that configure is hidden now)**
[image]

**3. Header completely gone!**

[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you share your layout and style code? Is your Toolbar defined in XML?

Comment: @AviParshan I'm using fragments for tabs and the mainactivity uses CoordinatorLayout. Could that create a problem?

Comment: Yes, I had a similar issue with the coordinator layout. Try using the regular style and comment out the toolbar stuff in coordinator layout, just to see if it will work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing coordinator layout to normal layout fixed it. I don't know why but it does the job for now.